# Python variable scope capture rules

Tags: python-3.x, scope

I am trying to understand local/global/nonlocal capture rules for python scoping and have encountered some asymmetric behavior, here is an example:

```py
def test():
    i = 0
    d = dict()
    def next():
        d[len(d)] = 'foo' # why is nonlocal d not required?
        nonlocal i # Required to pull 'i' into next.locals()
        i += 1
    while i < 10:
        next()

test()
```

From the above snippet we have variables `d` and `i` declared and defined as `dict` and `int` types respectively. However in the nested function `next` only `d` can be reached, `i` requires the `nonlocal` term to pull `i` into the function's scope.

I next theorized that non-referenceable types in python get lifted into the context of it's children's scope.
However this next example contradicts my theory:

```py
def test2():
    def If():
        return True if qn == None else qn

    def Ask():
        nonlocal qn
        qn = i < lim
        return If()

    qn = None
    i = 0
    lim = 5
    while i < 10:
        i += 1
        print(i, Ask())
```

Notice that in `test2`'s `Ask` function I do not need to declare `nonlocal i` and `nonlocal lim` but require `nonlocal qn`.

Is this behavior expected? I would assume either both should require `nonlocal` or neither would require it.

Is there a language specification I can reference for similar types of behavior?

Comment: `nonlocal d` isn't required because you _don't assign to `d`_ in that scope. You can _read from_ outer scopes' identifiers without `global`/`nonlocal`, you just can't _write to_ them.

Comment: I thought `d[...] =` is an assignment expression since the `__getitem__` method performs writes to the object?

Comment: It is an assignment _statement_, but it's not reassigning the actual identifier. If it did, e.g. `d = dict(foo="bar")` you'd see there's no asymmetry.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong You can mutate the object, you just can't reassign it. `i += 1` won't work because `int`s are immutable.

Comment: @Axe319 it makes sense now thanks!